# Java Authentication with Office 365 Sharepoint

Tags: office-365, rest, authentication

I have an application that I tested out with a self-created SharepointServer based on an Active Directory environment. 
For this I used the following code to authenticate with the Sharepoint server(which worked)

```
    public void authenticate() {
    Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
        @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                logger.info("Authenticated with user: " + user + " and password: " + password);
                return new PasswordAuthentication (user, password.toCharArray());
            }
    });
}
```

Now however, they have given me access to an Office 365 environment with a Sharepoint site containing multiple files that have to be read through the API.
They have given me a login and a password through which I can log on to the site and check to contents but I am not able to connect to this API (403 error).
I have tried the

```
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Required=f
```

as a header but also without success. Is there a way I can get my java program authenticated with this online sevice?

Answer (score 0):

Google's Google Search Appliance is open sourced so you can use it as a nice working example of Office 365 authentication. See: https://github.com/googlegsa/sharepoint/blob/master/src/com/google/enterprise/adaptor/sharepoint/LiveAuthenticationHandshakeManager.java